# Apple Backup Restore to Android

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios

After reading the articles in the the latest Apple event (September/15) I remember reading something about Apple introducing the ability to restore backed up media/contacts to an Android device. I am not sure if this is an IOS 9 feature or an ICloud feature.

Since I read this I cannot find the original article or any other reference to this functionality.

Perhaps someone read or saw something about this and could provide me with a link or more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As if Apple would ever provide a way for you to leave them.

What you may be thinking of is Apple's [Move to iOS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios) app that went live on Google Play on September 16th (also iOS 9's release date), which lets you transfer everything from an Android to a new iDevice, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks yes this must be it http://www.engadget.com/2015/06/08/apple-move-to-ios/ I must of misread.